# How can I extend the explorer context menu with QT?

Tags: c++, qt, explorer

I want to add right click menu items to the explorer (i.e. when you right click on the desktop), but for all the os'es. Therefore, I was wondering if there is a QT way of doing this?

Comment: I may be wrong (because of my lack of windows programming knowledge), but Qt is a GUI framework of its own, so its intended to write an application, not create 'plugins' for windows itself. You might need to be looking at another framework

Comment: @jdi yes, generally you are correct. However, there are certain 'plugin' like features. One such example is the `QSystemTrayIcon` interface.

Comment: Well yes I know very well the QSystemTrayIcon. I have used it in my own app. But it doesn't let you make changes to the windows Explorer through it. It simply runs your app without a Taskbar entry and instead lives in the sys tray. Its still its own app

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are actually looking for is called shell extensions in Windows. Look on these links for starters, ask if you have any specific questions.

[How to write shell extensions with QT](http://www.qtcentre.org/threads/32104-howto-making-a-windows-shell-extension-with-qt-open-source-edition)

[How to write context menu shell extension](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/441/The-Complete-Idiot-s-Guide-to-Writing-Shell-Extens)

Comment: yes, but i was wondering if there was a cross-os way to do it (i.e. a library)

Comment: @chacham15: There is not a cross-os way to do this because it involves interacting with very specific OS-relative libraries.

Comment: I second @jdi on this. You will need a different solution on each system because these things are **very** system specific.